# How to install MySQL on my Mac and not require 1.13 GB?

Tags: mysql

I need a simple database on my MacBook for light web development (5 or 6 simple tables with a few hundred or a couple thousands rows).

I downloaded MySQL and was going to install it, but it says it requires 1.13GB of space.  This sounds excessively large for my needs, and I don't want to eat up all that disk space.

Is there a way to get the MySQL installer to install a much smaller/lightweight version?

Or is there a MySQL derivative that is smaller that would work for me?

Comment: You could consider SQLite. It's possible to trim down the MySQL install size, but the cost of a gigabyte of disk space is likely **dramatically** cheaper than your time.

Comment: [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) can offer a more minimal install, but it's still going to be as big as it's going to be. On my machine here it's ~450MB installed, not including user data. For what it's worth Postgres seems to have a smaller footprint, only about 36MB.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need referential integrity on your tables, why not try **sqlite**.